# Issues with dependencies when trying to configure Setup.hs despite having dependencies installed

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I've been provided with a Setup.hs file, along with another .hs file that contains the source code. Whenever I try to configure the install by the following:

> runhaskell Setup.hs configure

I get the error:

> Setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
>   binary >=0.4.0 && <0.6.0, haskeline ==0.6.*

I've since installed these dependencies using cabal, but when I try to run the Setup configure command again, I get the same error. I'm completely new to Haskell - is there another step I'm missing after doing a cabal install before trying to run Setup again?

Comment: What is the output of runhaskell --version?

Answer (score 7):

How did you install the packages?  If you installed them with the `--user`flag, then you also need to configure with the `--user` flag.

You can verify that the packages are installed by running `ghc-pkg list binary` and `ghc-pkg list haskeline`.  It will list the installed package versions matching that name along with where they are installed.

Comment: I installed the packages through cabal. I've verified that they are installed. Here's the output from that: "mawhidby$ ghc-pkg list binary
/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/612/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.3/package.conf.d
/Users/mawhidby/.ghc/i386-darwin-6.12.3/package.conf.d
   binary-0.5.0.2

mawhidby$ ghc-pkg list haskeline
/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/612/usr/lib/ghc-6.12.3/package.conf.d
/Users/mawhidby/.ghc/i386-darwin-6.12.3/package.conf.d
   haskeline-0.6.3.2"

Comment: @mawhidby: The packages are installed in your user database(/Users/mawhidby/...), but Cabal only searches the global database by default.  You need to add the --user flag when you configure.